# .NET Core MVC web API controller returns no data despite being identical to one that does

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to build web api's using .NET Core

I have created some sample data and returned it in the default `Get()` function in the ValuesController created by default

```
namespace CoreWebAppMultiFunction.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
         // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public List<Info> Get()
        {
            List<Info> info = new List<Info>();
            info.Add(new Info { ID = 0, Data = "this is on the test", Read = true });
            info.Add(new Info { ID = 2, Data = "this is also on the test", Read = false });
            return info;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

But when I create a new controller the new controller does not return anything, just a blank browser window. The browsers console has a 404: Unable to load resource with every URL I try to use.

```
namespace CoreWebAppMultiFunction.Controllers
{
    [Route("MoreInfo/[controller]")]
    public class MoreInfoController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public SomeMoreInfo SomeInfo()
        {
            return new SomeMoreInfo { ID = 0, data = "data", yesno = true };
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible that I am trying to access it incorrectly in the browser URL? Or is there something wrong with how I set up the controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Debugging step #1: Use Fiddler or your browser's developer tools to see exactly *what* the HTTP request is returning, and edit your question with that information.

Comment: Dou you intentionally make the route like `[Route("MoreInfo/[controller]")]`? Because, If you trying GET "api/MoreInfo" it will turn nothing.

Comment: Well I am trying to replicate the default ValuesController as closely as possible, the new controller responds with nothing with or without that Route...

Comment: I have tried to access it with a variety of different URL's...

Comment: The route would be `MoreInfo/MoreInfo`, which looks a bit strange to me...

Comment: Which URLs have you tried? With the current route (assuming no defaults for "SomeInfo") your URL will look something like /MoreInfo/MoreInfo/SomeInfo, which is presumably not what you intended?

Comment: I can't see any obstacles when calling `api/MoreInfo/SomeInfo` with the route `Route("api/MoreInfo")` Btw, you refer your controller name with "[controller]" in Route attribute, right?

Comment: For you need to have `Route("api/[controller])` for both the controllers. Then you should be able to access apis by `API/values` and `API/moreinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, adding a `route` above a class hides all the functions except the `HttpGet` functions. And if there are multiple they are treated like overloads or the service simply returns absolutely nothing.

Following the example class that gets auto created seems to have been a poor move and confused me.